# How to solve following system of partial differential equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let's have a system of equations
$$
 \begin{matrix} p_{1} - 2p_{2} - p_{4}x^{2}_{4}(x_{1} + 1) = 0 \\  p_{1} + p_{2}x_{1} + p_{3}x_{1}x_{3}^{2} = 0 \end{matrix}, \quad p_{i} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}.
$$
How to solve it? I can't simply express $p_{i}$ from first equation and substitute it to second.

Comment: Why can't you just substitute $p_2$ from the first into the second?

Comment: The answer is 

$$
u = f(x_{1}^2 - x_{2} + \frac{1}{x_{3}} - \frac{2}{x_{4}}).
$$
By substituting $p_{2}$ I only decrease the number of dimensions of equation's variables by one. So I don't know what to do.

Comment: So you know the answer? What do you want then? Prove all solutions are of this form, ...?

Comment: I want to understand the solution. After substitution you write I can get an answer 
$$
u = f(g(x_{i}), \varphi (x_{i})),
$$
but not the answer
$$
u = f(\psi (x_{i})).
$$